# How to change a component based on route or handlebars condition

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In my attempts to create a 'blog' app I am faced with the following challenge.

I have my global-header component that renders a header. This header will stay the same on all routes except if I am viewing a single blog post then I want to show header-single.

This is the handlebars logic I am trying to accomplish, if it makes sense:

```
{{#if single}}
    {{header-single}}
{{else}}
    {{header-global}}
{{/if}}
```

Here is my route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType

});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('user', { path: '/user/:id' } );
    this.route('single', { path: '/:id', } );
  });

  this.route('page', { path: '/:slug' } );
});




export default Router;
```

Here is my application.hbs where I need to change the header based on route:

```
<!-- Page Header -->
{{#if single}}
    {{header-single}}
{{else}}
    {{header-global}}
{{/if}}
<!-- Main Content -->

{{outlet}}

<!-- Footer -->
```

Comment: do you face any problem with handlebars logic ?

Comment: well yes, because {{#if single}} always evaluate as false. I will update my question with my routing

Comment: Where are you setting `single` property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement can be solved in many different ways.it depends on your use case.

Below is one approach,

In application.js controller, you can define computed property `single` which depends on `currentRouteName` property and in `application.hbs` you can write your logic.

**controllers/application.js**

```
single:Ember.computed('currentRouteName',function(){    
    if(this.get('currentRouteName') === 'posts.single'){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }),
```

**templates/application.hbs**

```
{{#if single}}
    {{header-single}}
{{else}}
    {{header-global}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: You are right, it really depends on the use case. I will update my question with my application.hbs.

Comment: updated my answer. if you can provide [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com) i can fix it for you.

Comment: I hope I've done it right :)

https://ember-twiddle.com/7daacf75ae3eaa7197e39577fe5c7af3?openFiles=serializers.post.js%2C

Comment: Minimum verifiable example would do good..anyway i just included `single` computed property in application.js controller. and i fixed some of the issues in your twiddle. update [twiddle-link](https://ember-twiddle.com/593c24e26e7ff7f765fdd56fe02d4677?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C&route=%2Fposts%2F139)

Comment: yaas, thank you very much @kumkanillam. I never gave controllers a thought because all around the net people are saying: Controllers and Views are dead - Don't use them! And there you go, first line of the documentation on controllers: Controllers behave like a specialized type of Component that is rendered by the router when entering a Route.